# Problem With Delete File on server with mvc

Tags: model-view-controller

```
                FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uploadurl + Url);
                request.KeepAlive = false;
                request.UseBinary = true;
                request.UsePassive = true;
                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);


                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DeleteFile;
                FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                response.Close();
```

This is my code... but after run this code, my image dont delete on server!
all access permission on server for ftp user and file and folder has true.
help me pls...

Comment: Hi there, you may want to edit the tags to indicate what technologies you are using. Model-View-Controller is used by a lot of different languages and frameworks.

Comment: hi...yes. i use mvc. pass url to action with jquery ajax.

Comment: So you probably want to add ajax jquery to your list of tags.

Comment: no. i use ajax post for pass (Url Image) to my Action with name (_deleteFile(string Url))... and after this Url file should delete on server.

Comment: I found the problem.
ftp should always put a above folder.
Until the delete file in path is applied correctly.

Comment: MVC can mean a lot of things. Asp.net MVC, ruby MVC - MVC is a design pattern used by a lot of languages and projects. Hence the recommendation you add extra tags in the future so people know what technology stack you are talking about. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller